# geom_smooth or stat_function with geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I cannot get `ggplot2` to display a `geom_smooth()` or `stat_function()` with my boxplot.

I ultimately want to display a custom `stat_function` overtop of a boxplot.

```
library(ggplot2)
#joke dataset, similar looking ish to my own data
data=data.frame(date=as.Date(c("2011-02-01","2011-02-01","2011-02-01","2011-    02-01","2011-02-01",
                         "2011-02-10","2011-02-10","2011-02-10","2011-02-10","2011-02-10",
                         "2011-02-20","2011-02-20","2011-02-20","2011-02-20","2011-02-20",
                         "2011-02-28","2011-02-28","2011-02-28","2011-02-28","2011-02-28",
                         "2011-03-10","2011-03-10","2011-03-10","2011-03-10","2011-03-10"),format="%Y-%m-%d"),
            spore=c(0,1,0,1,0,
                    1,2,0,1,1,
                    8,5,6,12,7,
                    18,24,25,32,14,
                    27,26,36,31,22)
            )
#plots boxplot but not geom_smooth()
ggplot(data,aes(x=date,y=spore,group=date))+geom_boxplot()+geom_smooth()

#or maybe add a stat_function() so that I can have a logistic growth that way?
#this is a made up function, I have a real function for my own data
test <- function(x) {(40)/(1+exp((15/2)-(1/2)*x))}
ggplot(data,aes(x=date,y=spore,group=date))+stat_function(fun=test)
```

I think the fact that my x values are dates is screwing me up, but I don't have a good work around for this.
I am really at the end of my rope, and I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the dates. It's the group aesthetic. For `geom_boxplot` having groups will make nice seperate boxplots, but for `geom_smooth` it will try to make a smooth for each group, i.e. one point per line, i.e. no lines. The fix is straight-forward:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=date,y=spore)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(group=date)) + 
  geom_smooth()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect!